# Swipe through pages in WordPress, iPad

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-mobile, swipe

I'm working on a project were i need to be able to swipe through pages in WordPress using an iPad (the website is ipad-only, no functionality for other platforms needed).

A rough description of the project:

- Homepage with a collection (eg list) of articles or posts
- When the user reads one of these articles he/she should be able to swipe left or right to go to the next article chronologically (preferably with some kind of page transition effect).
- We want a magazine feeling

Since we use a custom designed theme it's not an option to use Onswipe or other themes. The ipad-swipe plugin might work for blogs but not in this case since it lacks page transitions. We tried using jQuery Mobile outside WordPress but since we only need the swipe and the page transition effect it feels too complicated.

We're not experienced in working with Wordpress, but have knowledge of HTML/CSS, JavaScript and PHP.

Are there any options besides creating our own plugin for Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite easy.

Implement jQueryMobile manualy or use some plugin.

Whe you have got jQuery mobile in just use "data-transition='slide'" and the page will animate. Please refer here to transitions http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/docs-transitions.html

If you have any question feel free to write me

Comment: Thank you for the answer. We have tried different JavaScript libraries, jQuery Mobile being one of them. The swipe and the animations worked fine, but the structure of jQuery mobile limits us too much. We also experienced major problems with the pages being "jumpy" and swipes were triggered when scrolling vertically. When we added a lot of content it got more buggy.